# Using custom lock print number in sequence using two threads where one is printing even other is printing odd numbers

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

There are two threads,one is to print even numbers another prints odd numbers. With the help of below custom lock i want to print number in sequence. The problem is after printing some numbers(displayed number are in correct sequence.) threads are getting deadlocked.I spent more then an hour still unable to find issue,for me everything seems fine.

```
public class Main{
       public static void main(String[] args){
           Lock lock=new Lock();
           SharedData sharedData=new SharedData(lock);

           Thread th1=new Thread(new EvenWriter(sharedData));
           Thread th2=new Thread(new OddWriter(sharedData));

           th1.start();
           th2.start();
       } 
    }
    class SharedData{
        Lock lock;
        boolean printOdd;
        SharedData(Lock lock){
           this.lock=lock;
           this.printOdd=true;
        }
    }
    class OddWriter implements Runnable{
        SharedData sharedData;
        int num;
        Lock lock;
        public OddWriter(SharedData sharedData){
           this.sharedData=sharedData;
           this.num=1;
           this.lock=sharedData.lock;
        }
        public void run(){
           while(true){
             if(sharedData.printOdd){
               lock.lock();
               System.out.println(num);
               num=num+2;
               sharedData.printOdd=false;
               lock.unlock();
            }
           }
        }
    }
    class EvenWriter implements Runnable{
        SharedData sharedData;
        int num;
        Lock lock;
        public EvenWriter(SharedData sharedData){
           this.sharedData=sharedData;
           this.num=2;
           this.lock=sharedData.lock;
        }
        public void run(){
           while(true){
             if(!sharedData.printOdd){
               lock.lock();
               System.out.println(num);
               num=num+2;
               sharedData.printOdd=true;
               lock.unlock();
            }
           }
        }
    }
    class Lock{

        private boolean locked=false;
        public synchronized void lock(){

            while(locked){
               try{
                 wait();
               }
               catch(Exception e){
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }

            locked=true;
        }
        public synchronized void unlock(){
            locked=false;
            try{
              notifyAll();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `printOdd` needs to be `volatile`.

Comment: Thank you.volatile solved the problem. I got the reason,it was happening because threads were reading data from cpu cache not from main memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `printOdd` `volatile`, e.g.

```
class SharedData{
    Lock lock;
    volatile boolean printOdd;
    SharedData(Lock lock) {
       this.lock=lock;
       this.printOdd=true;
    }
}
```

This is because you use `printOdd` across multiple threads; the purpose of `volatile` is to ensure that a piece of memory is accessible by all threads. What you were doing before was allowing access of `printOdd` to just the `OddWriter` thread, because it was the first thread to access it.

Answer (score -1):

the data that is shared between two thread is to be atomic. Here in your case the `boolean printOdd` is shared between the thread which is the cause for the deadlock.
Can you used

`AtomicBoolean printOdd;`

Comment: AtomicBoolean class internally uses volatile int. I am not sure what is the reason for downvote?

Comment: Atomicity is irrelevant to the problem.